# Syncfusion GridDataControl and DataContext Issue

Tags: wpf, syncfusion

i needed to add a simple button in a GridDataControl. note complicated so far.

```
<syncfusion:GridDataVisibleColumn HeaderText="Open Unit" MappingName="JobNumber">
    <syncfusion:GridDataVisibleColumn.HeaderStyle>
        <syncfusion:GridDataColumnStyle HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    </syncfusion:GridDataVisibleColumn.HeaderStyle>
    <syncfusion:GridDataVisibleColumn.CellItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>                                        
            <Button HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                    Name="cmdOpenUnit" 
                    Click="cmdOpenUnit_Click" 
                    Content="Open Unit" />   
        </DataTemplate>
    </syncfusion:GridDataVisibleColumn.CellItemTemplate>
</syncfusion:GridDataVisibleColumn>
```

Now i tried the `GridDataUnboundVisibleColumn` but by using it i cannot use a mapping name therefore when i look for `DataContext`, there isn't any. So i used `GridDataUnboundVisibleColumn` and set `MappingName="JobNumber"` to a random data in the source just to make sure i have `DataContext`

The click event :

```
private void cmdOpenUnit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        CUnit obj = ((Button)sender).DataContext as CUnit ;
    }
    catch { }
}
```

I have a grid with `ObservableCollection<CProject>` as Datasource then when you choose one the `CProject.UnitList // <-- ObservableCollection<CUnit>` become the Datasource of the currect grid i am working with. Therefore each row in the grid is a specific `CUnit`.

The problem is that the DataContext on `((Button)sender).DataContext` is the `JobNumber` data in the `Cunit` object but i cannot get the parent property. i tried different casting but couldn't get anything yet. I have used this method a couple time with sucess but it's my first time doing this with syncfusion and they help files contains nothing about that.

the DataContext of the Sender i received is of type `Syncfusion.Windows.Controls.Grid.GridDataCellBoundWrapper` if that might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After couple message back and forth with Syncfusion, turns out the data context do not actually contain the data context per say. you need couple cast and mouse pointer location to find it out.